# Can I Add custom Follow up action to Outlook tasks context menu?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I would like to add custom Follow Up Action for tasks and manipulate all selected tasks in that action. How can I do that with Outlook addon ?

Here is the picture of what I want :

[image]